# Why is this scalar value returning an int of 1? (Chomp)

Tags: perl

$receiver is returning 1.

```
print "Who is receiving this message?:";
my $receiver = chomp(my $r = <STDIN>);
print $receiver;
```

Also, where can I find some more documentation about chomp? Thank you.

Comment: Googling for "perl chomp" leads you right to the docs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) returns the number of input record separator (whatever is in `$/`) characters removed from the end of each string in its argument list. It should be used:

```
chomp(my $reciever = <STDIN>);
```

`chomp` can be used on arrays and lists, which is, I assume, the reason for this functionality:

```
my $count = chomp(@array);
```

The documentation for `chomp` is in [`perldoc -f chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html)

Answer (score 3):

It returns the total number of characters removed from all its arguments.

See http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html

Instead, you probably want `chomp(my $receiver = <STDIN>);`

Answer (score 2):

Because `chomp` returns the number of newline characters removed from its argument(s). Take a look at [`perldoc -f chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) for more information.

What you probably want is `chomp(my $receiver = <STDIN>);`

Answer (score 1):

because you use it wrong.

```
use Modern::Perl; 
my $receiver; 
chomp($receiver = <STDIN>); 
say "Result: " . $receiver;'
```

More Information:

```
perldoc -f chomp
```

or http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html

Answer (score 0):

Chomp does "in-place" removal and returns the number of characters removed.

This is wrong:

```
my $var = <STDIN>;
my $result = chomp ($var);  ### here, $result will have '1' and not the chomped string of <STDIN>
```

This is correct:

```
my $var = <STDIN>;
chomp ($var);
```