# Perl: Until condition never evaluates as true

Tags: perl, loops

I'm a Perl newbie, trying to figure out why my Until condition never evaluates as true in a basic number-guessing game.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Ex 10-1

use warnings;

$num = int(1 + rand 100);
print "\$num is $num\n";                # Debug

print "I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100. What number is it?\n";
until (chomp($guess = <STDIN>) == $num) {
    print "\$guess is $guess\n";        # Debug
    if ($guess =~ /\A\s*(quit|exit)?\s*\z/) {
        print "Exiting.\n";
        exit 0;
    } elsif ($guess =~ /\D/) {
        print "Invalid input. ";
    } else {
        ($guess < $num) ? (print ("Too low. ")) : (print ("Too high. "));
    }
    print ("Guess again.\n");
}
print ("Congrats! You guessed the number.\n");
exit 0;
```

Here's an example of execution:

```
$ ./ex1
$num is 4
I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100. What number is it?
5
$guess is 5
Too high. Guess again.
3
$guess is 3
Too low. Guess again.
4
$guess is 4
Too high. Guess again.
```

Comparing $guess to $num, $guess equals $num when 4 is entered, satisfying the test condition. Yet it enters the loop anyway and makes it to the final (default) result of printing "Too high."

I've also tried adding another set of parentheses around chomp($guess = ), which didn't help.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is this scalar value returning an int of 1? (Chomp)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13001954/why-is-this-scalar-value-returning-an-int-of-1-chomp)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) returns the number of characters removed, not the modified argument after `chomp`-ing, so you shouldn't be using the return value in your loop condition.

```
chomp(my $guess = <STDIN>);

until ($guess == $num) {
    ...
    chomp($guess = <STDIN>);
}
```

Comment: Or `until ( chomp( my $guess = <≥ ), $guess == $num ) { ... }`

Comment: @Borodin Sure, TMTOWTDI

Comment: My way has the advantage of conforming to *Don't Repeat Yourself*

Comment: Big thanks to both of you. Matt's explanation reminded me exactly how I was being dumb (which is what I asked for lol), and Borodin's way is how I was trying to go about this.
I will say though, when I use 'my' as in Borodin's example, it fails the same way as in the OP, but with new warnings. When I leave out 'my', it works flawlessly. Warnings when I use 'my':
Name "main::guess" used only once: possible typo at ./ex1 line 9.
Use of uninitialized value $guess in numeric eq (==) at ./ex1 line 9, <> line 1.